# Where dose the compiler encounter floatinng point int the below program? What is the meaning of core dumped?

Tags: c++

The below code is returning floating point error, where does it find the error from?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x[10];
    int y = 1000000000;
    long z = 2312432321;
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a = z/y;
        x[i] = a;
        y /= 10;
        z %= y;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        cout << x[j] << " ";
    }

}
```

//output Floating point exception (core dumped).

Comment: Begin by using a *debugger* to catch the crash, and locate where in your code it happens. Then look at the involved variables to see their values. My ***guess***? `y` becomes zero and you divide by it.

Comment: You should run your code under a debugger.  The problem appears to be at `z %= y;` with `y == 0`.

Comment: How to learn to use debugger? which ide could be worth it ?

Comment: @RaphaelHawk It really depends on what you need, what platform you use, what you already know, what you think can be good for your future, if can pay for it ... What you should do is search for the most common options, and compare them by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes at execution time, not at compile time (so it is not the compiler that encounters the error).

On the last iteration, `y /= 10` makes `y` be `0`, so `z %= y` throws an error.

Also, as mentionned in the comments, you should use a debugger to detect those errors, that will help you in many situations, and save you a lot of time.

Comment: Some SO users seem downvote an answer if a question is primitive and does not worth get answered, or is already answered in a comment prior an answer was posted.

Comment: i do not know about the problem of your explanation but the problem with my code was that z %= y happens after y /= 10 so until the last iteration y becomes 0 before z,  the same stuff you told. May be u also had to say this.